# Waiting for network link to be up before continuing in bash

Tags: bash, networking, ping, ifconfig

Is there a way to check for successful network interface link for multiple interfaces in a bash script before continuing?

Something like:

```
eth0 eth1 eth2 eth3 network interfaces are brought up
Wait for link detection on all 4 interfaces
Proceed
```

Comment: in a loop try 1x ping in every second to some known host what are in the each network, or check ifconfig output...

Comment: If they are up, it doesn't necessarily mean that the other hosts respond to pings.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can check if the network interfaces' names appear after running `ifconfig -s`.

Something like:

```
if [ $( ifconfig -s | grep eth0 ) ]; then echo "eth0 is up!"
```

Check [*this link*](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/ubuntu-linux-view-the-status-of-my-network-interfacescard.html) for more details.

---

To make this test ongoing, you can do something like what @jm666 said:

```
while ! ping -c 1 -W 1 1.2.3.4; do
    echo "Waiting for 1.2.3.4 - network interface might be down..."
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: This is great if I just want to test once, but what if I need to actively wait for until it comes online and then proceed?

Comment: Why do you have a `-W` flag in there?  You didn't specify a timeout for a single ping....

Comment: `-c 1 -W 1` means "*try 1 echo, and wait for it for 1 second at most*".  If it does not receive the echo back, then enters the if-block, shows the message, and wait for one second before trying again.

Comment: If you didn't specify `-W 1`... how long would it wait for? I dont see a descrp in the man pages

Comment: As far as I understand, `-c 1` alone will just send one echo and wait for it to return, no matter how long it takes.  Adding the `-W 1` will prevent this from waiting too long, allowing just 1 second of time to get a response.

Comment: The while loop as presented (`while ! ping -c 1 -W 1 1.2.3.4;`) doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 18... It will correctly continue if the network is not available but will also continue if I get a valid ping result. I had to change it to `while ! (ping -c 1 -W 1 1.2.3.4 | grep -q 'statistics');`